# How to create a our own custom view in android

Tags: android, xml

I want to create my own `view` like how android provide the `Gallery` and the `GridView` .

My requirement is something like i should display my `icons/images`(take any widgets) in the circular view.

I am confused how to do it?

Either to go with new view or i can solve it by using animation or something else.

Can any one  tell me how to start with?

I assume to create a new view we should code at framework layer... Is it right?

Or I can get it done in application layer only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about this ? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx

Comment: hey kartik thanku .. this is similar to what i was looking for .. but thing is it some what looks like oval shaped,,, i want it in complete circular form or you can say it like a wheel shaped .. any ways i ll try with it how to achieve 

thanks Shilpa

Comment: @karthik : in this view the onclick is not working properly .. all items are not getting selected whereas they are only visible ... any help please...